# How to direct user to its specific activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building an app in which when the user first installs it, In the MainActivity(Launcher Activity) the app asks what type of user he is(Let's say Driver or Rider)? Based on the user selection he is directed to the corresponding login screen. After the user is logged in he directed to HomeActivity. If he closes the app without logging out, next time he opens the app he should directly see the HomeActivity(based on what usertype he selected). For one user the code in the MainActivity would be like:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        sendToStart();

    }
}

private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverHomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();
}
```

I am new to Android and Firebase. I don't how this should be done for two types users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one login screen, in that screen the user can choose work type(two buttons or radio buttons).

If he chooses Driver, then create a Driver node in the database with the information he wrote and direct him to the home activity:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers").child(user.getUid());
ref.child("name").setValue(name);
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DriverHomeActivity.class);
startActivity(startIntent);
finish();
```

Also do the same for Rider.

---

If the user, closes the app without logging out. In the first activity that should open (ex: splash activity), check if there is a current user and check type of user:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
DatabaseReference driver = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drivers"); 
DatabaseReference rider = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Riders");

  if (user != null) {
    driver.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) { 
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DriverHomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RiderHomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                  }
            @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
```

Here in the splash activity, it will check if there is a current user(if user is logged in) `user.getUid()` will return the current userid and then it will check if this userid is under the `Drivers` node, and then it directs him to the driver's home activity.

Comment: The code above seems correct to me but even if I am logged in as Driver, the app opens up the RiderHomeActivity.

Comment: I have checked it many times and it is always directing to RiderHomeActivity.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I have got my mistake there's a node Users inside which Drivers and Rider nodes are present. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in manifest
and also 
you should save user type with user ID in database and at start app check this first and then show home page.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity/>    
    <activity android:name=".DriverHomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Please check the question asked carefully and then answer.

Comment: you should save user type with user ID in database and at start app check this first and then show home page.

Comment: Add this in your answer, instead of commenting here.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be solved by the usage of `SharedPreference` mechanism.
Here you can keep the login status in `SharedPreference` like below:-.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
prefs.edit().putBoolean("login", true).commit();
```

when the user won't logged out and coming back, you should check the login status in splash screen using the `SharedPreference` variable and moved the user to corresponding activity.

Boolean loginStatus = prefs.getBoolean("login", false);

```
if (loginStatus) {
// Move to Home activity
} else {
//Move to login screen
}
```

Little bit documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider keeping a `LauncherActivity` in your android application which will decide which activity to launch further. A sample `LauncherActivity` might look like the following.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean isLoggedInAsDriver = getSharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_driver", false);
        startApplication(isLoggedInAsDriver);
        finish();
    }

    private void startApplication(boolean isLoggedInAsDriver) {
        Intent intent;
        if (isLoggedInAsDriver) {
            intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, DriverActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, RiderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Your application can have only one launcher, so mark the `LauncherActivity` as the launcher of your android application in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like the following.

```
<activity
    android:name=".LauncherActivity"
    android:label="Your app name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now you may have noticed that I have used a flag (i.e. `isLoggedInAsDriver`) to start the desired activity from the `LauncherActivity`. This is a preference data that you need to store in your `SharedPreferences` when you can determine if the user is a driver or rider. Then each time your application launches via your `LauncherActivity`, check the stored value and get the user type. Based on the user type, launch the second activity.

Comment: I don't know anything about SharedPreferences. Can you provide the code about which you are talking in the last paragraph. Should a make java class for that or what?